# problem in finding average for a nested linq query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core project. And I have multiple tables called **ApiApp**, **ApiAppHistory** and **Entity**.

- In **ApiApp** table, I have **date** field which is of type `string`(yyyy/mm/dd) and a field `ApplicantID`.
- In **ApiAppHistory** there is a field called **LastReqStatus** which is of type `int` and its related value is stored in Entity table.
- Now I want to group by `Year`, `Month`, `LastReqStatus` and `ApplicantID` to find for each **month** of a **year** for how many `ApplicantID` the `LastReqStatus` is equal to **Granted**.
- And after finding that, I want to know the **average** for each **month** of a **year** that all the `ApplicantIDs` has `lastReqStatus == "Granted"`.

For the former I wrote a query like the following:

```
var avg = from t1 in _context.Apiapp
          join t2 in _context.ApiAppHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiAppId
          join t3 in _context.Entity on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
          where t1.IsDeleted == false && t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id && t3.Name == "Granted"
                group new {t1,t2}
                by new { t2.LastReqStatus, Year = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4), Month = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2) , Applicant = t1.ApplicantId } into g

                    select new
                             {

                                 Year = g.Key.Year, 
                                 Month = g.Key.Month,
                                 Applicant = g.Key.Applicant,
                                 GrantedCount = g.Count()
                             };

var GrantedReqAVG = avg.ToList();
```

```
public partial class ApiApplicantHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? SentType { get; set; }
        public int? Reason { get; set; }
        public int? LastReqStatus { get; set; }
        public int? ApiAppId { get; set; }

        public virtual Apiapp ApiApp { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType LastReqStatusNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType SentTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType ReasonNavigation { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class EntityType
    {
        public EntityType()
        {
ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();            ApiApplicantHistorySentTypeNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
            ApiApplicantHistoryReasonNavigation = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EntityKey { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistoryLastReqStatusNavigation { get; set; }        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiAppHistorySentTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiAppHistoryReasonNavigation { get; set; }

    }
}

public partial class Apiapp
    {
        public Apiapp()
        {
            ApiApplicantHistory = new HashSet<ApiApplicantHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public int? LastRequestStatus { get; set; }
        public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
        public string ApiRequestDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiApplicantHistory> ApiApplicantHistory { get; set; }
    }
```

But about the finding average I don't have any opinion how can I do that. I appreciate if anyone help me.
For Instance, I have the following data in **ApiApp** table :
ApiApp:

```
ID:1 LastRequestStatus:1 ApplicantID:1 ApiRequestDate:2019/02/03
ID:2 LastRequestStatus:2 ApplicantID:1 ApiRequestDate:2019/02/16

ID:3 LastRequestStatus:10 ApplicantID:2 ApiRequestDate:2019/02/01
ID:4 LastRequestStatus:19 ApplicantID:2 ApiRequestDate:2019/02/20
ID:5 LastRequestStatus:31 ApplicantID:2 ApiRequestDate:2019/02/29
```

Thus the average should be:

> (2 + 3)/2 it means 2 is for ID:1 and ID:2 which has same Applicant #1 who requested in month Feb and 3 is for ID:3 and ID:4 and ID:5 which has same Applicant #2 who requested in month Feb and because in month Feb there are just two applicant #1 and #2 thus we have to divide the numerator to 2.

Comment: can you show an example for grouped result and the expected result after average? you are said **I want to group by Year, Month, LastReqStatus and ApplicantID**, but here you are grouping just by ``LastReqStatus ``.

Comment: Does my query has a problem for grouping all of them? I thought its syntax is correct for grouping all those 4 fileds. If it has problem, I appreciate if you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: I suggest that you provide us with the complete structure of your three tables for reference. It is best to provide the data of your current three tables. Your description only involves part of it. We cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: ``group new { Year = , Month =  , Applicant = } by new { t2.LastReqStatus }``: this mean group by ``t2.LastReqStatus`` the column ``Year``,``Month`` and ``Applicant``, not group by ``Year``,``Month`` ,``Applicant`` and ``LastReqStatus``.

Comment: @Sajid, based on your code, I still have a few questions. `ApplicantID` does not appear in the `ApiApp`  class. Maybe you should provide `OnModelCreating` to us for reference.
And what does one of the where conditions in linq  `t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id`  stand for? If you are joining the Apiapp and ApiAppHistory tables, `on t1.Id equals t2.ApiAppId`  has been done, you do not need to add this where condition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because for each record in ApiApp there are multiple records in ApiApplicantHistory and I just want the last registered record in ApiApplicant History for each ApiApp record and to find it, I should join via t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id as well

Comment: @hrz after updating you request ``avg``, if we take the example : ``[{2019,5,1,50},{2019,5,2,50},{2019,4,1,50}]``, the average will be : ``Month 5 ==> 75`` and ``Month 4 ==> 75``?

Comment: @hrz i have added an answer,after updating the question by an example of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update :

1 - You don't need to group by `LastRequestStatus`, just `Year`,`Month` and  `ApplicantId`

```
var groupedApplicant = from t1 in _context.Apiapp
                       join t2 in _context.ApiAppHistory on t1.Id equals t2.ApiAppId
                       join t3 in _context.Entity on t2.LastReqStatus equals t3.Id
                       where t1.IsDeleted == false && t1.LastRequestStatus == t2.Id && t3.Name == "Granted"
                       group new { t1, t2 }
                       by new { Year = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(0, 4), Month = t1.ApiRequestDate.Substring(5, 2), t1.ApplicantId } into g

                       select new
                       {
                           Year = g.Key.Year,
                           Month = g.Key.Month,
                           Applicant = g.Key.ApplicantId
                           GrantedCount = g.Count()
                       };
```

This request will give :

```
Year:2019,Month:2,Applicant:1,GrantedCount:2
Year:2019,Month:2,Applicant:2,GrantedCount:3
```

2 - Group `groupedApplicant` by `Year` and `Month` and select the average:

```
var avg = groupedApplicant
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month })
        .Select(x => new { x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month, Avg = x.Average(y => y.GrantedCount) })
        .ToList();
```

This request will give:

```
Year:2019,Month:2,Avg:2.5
```

I hope you find this helpful.